# Display a Form through CMD (VB.NET)

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments, vb.net

I've built a VB.NET program that contains multiple `Form`s. Now I want to display a particular `Form` (not the main/startup form) of the program through the Command Prompt.
For example, if there are two `Form`s in my program called `startup_form` and `msg_form`, I must run codes in CMD such that the program is executed but only `msg_form` is displayed and `startup_form` is hidden or not loaded at all.
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command line arguments.

Make your program recognize certain command line switches:

- `myprog.exe /startup`
- `myprog.exe /msg`

Within your code make it open and display the forms based on what switches are sent via the command line.

[Environment.GetCommandLineArgs Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)